# How to use setPassword outside of server methods

Tags: javascript, meteor, node-fibers

I need to use Accounts.setPassword outside of meteor server methods, but on server side. With collections in this case I use Fiber wrapper but it doesn't work with Accounts.setPassword.

```
Fiber(function(){Accounts.setPassword(msg.user_id, msg.password);}).run();
```

Comment: What is the result of that call?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and simple

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Accounts.setPassword("Jp2G9TJLHwqagQmMr", "654321")
  });
}
```

Works just fine on server side. However, if you pass your function in a callback (as an event handler), then don't forget to wrap it into `Meteor.bindEnvironment`:

```
something.on('event',
  Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    Accounts.setPassword(msg.user_id, msg.password);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('failed to bind env: ', err);
  })
);
```